# Library to manage dynamic update in react native

Tags: android, react-native, google-play

I am building a demo app in react native (hello World).It is build and running happily.Now i need to update the content of the app ( without updating through play store) from displaying hello world to hello world 1.So i need to update the JSBundle in the app.So far i tried to use the following library

1. aeroFS - react native auto updater (But this not upto date)
2. Code Push - this is really a nice library but the new update bundle needs to be pushed to the code push server which is not recommended in my use case as i develop for an organisation.

I tried to implement on my own using above libraries but not successful. Any help regarding this is highly appreciated

Comment: If we are talking about content, than I would recommend [firebase](https://firebase.google.com/) :)

Comment: @parohy thanks for your suggestion but i think you misundertood the content or i gave a wrong use case(updating hello world text).All i needed to do is update the app without play store using jsbundle file from remote server.the content here is the jsbundle file that react native uses to built the ui screen for the app(android/ios).

Comment: Ohh I was not sure what you referred content to. Well the prob best solution would be CodePush. If you would like to do some a/b testing on visuals I would use [taplytics](https://taplytics.com/), maybe this can suite your needs. But besides CodePush I do not know any other framework which updates jsbundle without updating appstore.

Comment: @parohy thanks i assume i need to create one since i need some more customization and since its for my organization i need to deploy the new bundle in my server rather than code push server which code push could not do.Any links or reference to do this will be helpful.